# SQLITE SUBQUERIES

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLITE Table that holds information in the following format. The first column is ID, second is ID_1, third is ID_2 and final column is Volume.

```
ID     ID_1 ID_2    Volume                      
1000    111 0       
1000    111 1                           
1000    111 2                           
1000    111 3                           
1000    112 0                           
1000    112 1                           
1000    112 2                           
1000    112 3                           
1000    113 0
```

There are 10 or more unique `ID` values, about 2000 unique `ID_1` values and 4 unique values for `ID_2`.

At the end I want to select volume for selected IDs, selected ID_1 and selected ID_2. Things work well this far. The output format should be - ID, ID_1, Volume

What I am confused about is to get the following data.

I need the following data:

For a given ID and ID_1, if ID_2 = 1, then

```
Volume = (Volume for ID, ID_1 and ID_2 = 1) - (Volume for ID, ID_1 and ID_2 = 2)- (Volume for ID, ID_1 and ID_2 = 3)
```

Otherwise print volume like it is.

I am using python to extract this data in a csv file. I am trying to store ID and ID_1 into value1 and value2 and using that in subquery but it doesnt seem to be working.

My code looks like the following:

```
import os
import sqlite3
import shutil 
import csv
import time
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

value1 ="va"
value2 ="pa"

working_dir = "C:\Path"

aimsun_db_filename = os.path.join(working_dir,"File.sqlite")

conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)

c= conn.cursor()


SQL  = '''

SELECT 
    TableName.ID   '''=  value1  +''',   
    TableName.ID_1 '''= value2 +''',        
    CASE WHEN ID_2 = 1 THEN 
            (SELECT TableName.volume
            FROM TableName
            WHERE 
            ID_2 = 2 and
            TableName.oid = '''+value1+''' AND 
            TableName.did = '''+value2+'''
            )
        WHEN ID_2 = 2 THEN  
            TableName.volume
        WHEN ID_2 = 3 THEN  
            TableName.volume
        ELSE 
            "Other"
        END,
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE 
        AND NOT sid = 0
        AND NOT ent = 0
'''

with conn:
 c = conn.cursor()
 c.execute(SQL)
 while True:
    row = c.fetchone()

    if row ==None:
        break
```

Comment: What would happen, for example, for `ID_1=2` and `ID_2=3`?  I'm not seeing an obvious pattern for what you are trying to do.

Comment: ID_2 = 2 Represent Cars; ID_2 = 3 Represent Heavy Vehicles; ID_2 = 1 Represent All Vehicles. So, in the end I want 1-(2+3) which will give me volume for Bus.

Comment: ID_2 = 0 represent all PCUs

Comment: Don't ever use string concatenation to form SQL queries -- this is the path to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: `WHERE AND` is not valid. Is there supposed to be something before `AND`?

Comment: sid is a typo for ID_2 and you can ignore the ent here. I was trying to group ID before AND but took it out later.

Comment: What is `TableName.ID   '''=  value1  +''',` supposed to be? You can't assign to a string literal. Is that `=` a typo for `+`?

Comment: Barmar, I want to store value from TableName.ID into a variable to use it later in the CASE WHEN. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the input file is as follows

[Input Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHTK7.jpg)

Format of the output file is:
[Output Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC3DX.jpg)